# PyLDAvis, getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, nlp, valueerror, lda, pyldavis

Using PyLDAvis to try to visualize the LDA model created using genism. Below is the code:

Libraries Imported

```
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models.ldamodel import LdaModel
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
import spacy
import pyLDAvis 
import pyLDAvis.gensim
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
```

Lemmetization function:

```
def lemmatization(texts, allowed_postags=["NOUN", "ADJ", "VERB", "ADV"]):
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["parser", "ner"])
    texts_out = []
    for text in texts:
        doc = nlp(text)
        new_text = []
        for token in doc:
            if token.pos_ in allowed_postags:
                new_text.append(token.lemma_)
        final = " ".join(new_text)
        texts_out.append(final)
    return (texts_out)


lemmatized_texts = lemmatization(sentiment_df['rationale'])
print (lemmatized_texts[0][0:90])
```

Giving correct output: `work well partner more solo worker especially early morning`

Dictionary creation:

```
def gen_words(texts):
    final = []
    for text in texts:
        new = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text, deacc=True)
        final.append(new)
    return (final)

data_words = gen_words(lemmatized_texts)
data_words = list(filter(None,data_words))

id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_words)

corpus_new = []
for text in data_words:
    new = id2word.doc2bow(text)
    corpus_new.append(new)

print (corpus_new[2][0:20])

word = id2word[[2][:1][0]]
print (word)
```

Giving correct output: [(5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (11, 1), (12, 1), (13, 1), (14, 1)]
like

LDA model:

```
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus_new,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=30,
                                           random_state=100,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=10,
                                           alpha="auto")
```

Visualization using PyLDAvis:

```
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word, mds="mmds", R=30)
vis
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f184c148aa16> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
----> 2 pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word, mds="mmds", R=30)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gensim/matutils.py in corpus2csc(corpus, num_terms, dtype, num_docs, num_nnz, printprogress)
    150 
    151             # zip(*doc) transforms doc to (token_indices, token_counts]
--> 152             doc_indices, doc_data = zip(*doc) if doc else ([], [])
    153             indices.extend(doc_indices)
    154             data.extend(doc_data)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Not able to pinpoint why this is happening, any help would be appreciated

Expected to see LDA visualization but got the above mentioned error

Comment: At `vis = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, id2word, mds="mmds", R=30)`, should it be `corpus_new` instead of `corpus`?